# Как изменить содержимое поля drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Нужно изменить содержимое поля материала drupal 7,
как это можно сделать программно?
Как использовать `hook_field_storage_write` ?
Подскажите кто знает?

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения содержимого поля материала можно использовать следующий код:

```
$node = node_load($nid); 
$l = field_language('node', $node, 'field_number');
$node->field_number[$l][0]['value'] = 10;
node_save($node);
```

Если установлен модуль [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity), то можно использовать [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers):

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$wrapper->field_number->set(10);
$wrapper->save();
```

Хук [hook_field_storage_write()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_storage_write/7.x) вызывается перед записью значений полей сущности при её создании/изменении, но для изменения значений сохраняемых полей крайне неудобен. Для этой цели лучше использовать [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) (для нодов) или [hook_entity_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7.x) (для всех сущностей).